# Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: unsafe-none

Tags: same-origin-policy

A new HTTP header named [`Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy) has three values:

- `unsafe-none`
- `same-origin-allow-popups`
- `same-origin`

[Google's web.dev article](https://web.dev/why-coop-coep/) about this header explains its effects on other sites (as in, cross-origin sites) that open sites with this header with regards to a separate *browsing context group*. [Scott Helme's blog post](https://scotthelme.co.uk/coop-and-coep/) goes into greater detail along with other new headers.

I assume that `unsafe-none` (the default behaviour) exists for backwards-compatibility reasons to preserve the existing behaviour of `window.open()`.

Are there any situations where you'd want to deliberately want your site to have the default behaviour of `unsafe-none` (either by setting the value explicitly or omitting the header) such that it is not isolated from another site's browsing context group?